# Socket.io emit special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working in a small project which is Socketio 0.9 based. Everything is working weell but i am having a small **issue with special characters**.

I am creating a dynamic JSON object from javascript in a web client wich is emited to the server:

```
var config = new Object();
config.name1 = 'Iñaki';
config.name2 = 'Óscar';
config.name3 = 'Alba';

var data = new Array();
data.push(config);

var myJson = new Object();
myJson.hash = hash;
myJson.serial = serial;
myJson.data = data;

iosocket.emit('config', myJson));
```

And in the server i am receiving end emiting it to other clients:

```
    socket.on('config', function (data) {
        ...
        socket.broadcast.to(myroom).emit("data", data.data);
    }
```

At this point, if i have any special chars like 'Iñaki' or 'Óscar' in my **config Javascript Object** my data is not emitted from socketio to my clients. But if i fill in the Object with non special characters names, it works out of the box.

¿Why?

**Note:** I cannot upgrade to socketio 1.x
**Note:** My server.js is UTF-8 saved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem today.

In my case the problem was that the socket.io version for server and client was not the same. I was using socket.io-client 2.0.1 and Socket.io 1.4.0 so downgrading socket.io-client version to 1.4.0 fixed the problem.